# Copying files from Bamboo to a Server

Tags: deployment, windows-services, bamboo

I am currently setting up a Bamboo job to deploy a windows service to our QA server. In order to do this I decided to stop the service, copy over the new files from Bamboo, and then restart the service. I am doing the following to copy the whole folder over to the destination.

```
<Copy SourceFiles="($SourceFolder)" DestinationFolder="($DeploymentFolder)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

What should I set the Source Folder to if I want to pull the files from Bamboo rather than my local machine?

Comment: Source folder should be checkout repository

Comment: @binarymemoir so going off of [the Bamboo variable documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO055/Bamboo+variables) would ${bamboo.build.working.directory} be the correct variable to pass?

Comment: Are you checking out any repository? also you must  be performing some compile/build task on that repo.  Is that windows service result of some build process?  If yes, under which directory it exists. You need to decide , what you want to deploy and then look where it is located.